# How to use conditional statement while writing and reading a .properties file in java

Tags: java

is there a way to use conditional statement in .properties file?
i want something like this as output in properties file:

```
'TP=1
   SatelliteFrequency of TP1=11240
   Polarization of TP1=Vertical
   SymbolRate of TP1=30
TP=2 
   SatelliteFrequency of TP2=11240
   Polarization of TP2=Vertical
   SymbolRate of TP2=30
TP=3
   SatelliteFrequency of TP3=11240
   Polarization of TP3=Vertical
   SymbolRate of TP3=30
....and so on upto 12 TPs`
```

Comment: Typically, a properties file indicates static data that the user can change at their will, but not anything that's conditional, since the file itself doesn't contain logic or the ability to do logic.  I'm also confused by what you mean by "output" - are you trying to create your own properties file?

Comment: No you cannot.  You can do it in Java when reading it.

Comment: A .properties file is just a text file with key=value pairs. That's it. No magic.

Comment: @Makoto : yes , i am trying to create my own .properties file

Comment: @BrianRoach i need to use conditional statement so that if tp=1, then satfreq=11240,sr=30,polarization=vertical... if tp=2,then satfreq=11234,sr=68,polarization=horizontal...and so on upto tp=12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your properties file

```
TP=1,2,3

SatelliteFrequency.TP.1 = 11240
Polarization.TP.1 = Vertical
SymbolRate.TP.1 = 30

SatelliteFrequency.TP.2 = 11240
Polarization.TP.2 = Vertical
SymbolRate.TP.2 = 30

SatelliteFrequency.TP.3 = 11240
Polarization.TP.3 = Vertical
SymbolRate.TP.3 = 30
```

In your java code you need to first read values of first property 'TP' into an array and iterate the same to read the 3 properties for each TP by appending the number to your property. Example `"Polarization.TP." + i"` where `i` is your loop index.

HTH.

Comment: Please explain it to me with suitable code,as i am new in java.

Comment: All you have to do is google 'Reading properties files in java', and you'll get plenty of good examples/code snippets. I'll do it for you this time. Here you go: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps instead of using a properties file u need to use a json file . THen u can achieve the conditional aspect .. Your json file will look as follows:

```
"TP":"1":{
   "SatelliteFrequency of TP1":"11240"
   "Polarization of TP1":"Vertical"
   "SymbolRate of TP1":"30"

// And so on .. 
}
```

You can then use any json libraries and parse it. I dont think u can achieve a condition in Properties file.. Its just a KV pair..

Comment: Brian Roach .. you are right :) .. Just wanted to put the idea across, wasnt concentrating on the syntax aspect.. will take care in future.